# Filling gaps between line features in QGIS Graphical Modeler

Tags: qgis, geometry, merge, qgis-modeler, polyline-creation

I want to merge lines and fill the gaps between them, but I cannot use the "Join multiple lines"-Plugin because I have to use the Graphical Modeler and in there is the plugin/tool not available. Does anyone know another approach?

[image: example line with gap]

Comment: I added a picture. If I use the merge lines tool it does not fill the existing gaps between the lines if I am not wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extract start and end points with ["Geometry by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) `start_point($geometry)` and `end_point($geometry)` as two separate point layers.

Execute ["Shortest line between features"](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#shortest-line-between-features) twice, with a "Maximum distance" set, one from start to end points, and one for  end to start points.

["Merge"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#merge-lines) the two shortest line layers.

["Delete duplicate geometries"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgisdeleteduplicategeometries).

If you want to - merge the resulting layer with your input layer, I haven't

[image]

Comment: looks great thank you, but can I integrate this in a graphical model builder workflow?

Comment: I've created a new workflow which you can use in modeler

Comment: thank you so much! you helped me a lot!

Comment: Actually I cant find the: "shortest line between" algorithm... At first I thought you renamed another algorithm in the graphical modeler, but I cant find another one with the same functions.  Im am using QGIS 3.22.10 by the way

Comment: It is called **Shortest line between features**, I have v. 3.26

Answer (score 2):

Try this workflow for the following input

[image: input]

**Step 1.** Use the ["Add autoincremental field"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#add-autoincremental-field) tool

[image: step1]

`x(centroid($geometry))` was applied for *'Sort expression'*

**Step 2.** ["Extract vertices"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#extract-vertices)

[image: step2]

**Step 3.** Apply the ["Points to path"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#points-to-path) geoalgorithm

[image: step3]

`"AUTO" || "vertex_index"` was used in *'Order expression'* and `"id"` as *'Path group expression'*